# Clarify $\lambda - \frac{\lambda(\lambda - 1)}{2!} + \frac{\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)}{3!}-\ldots = 1 - (1-1)^\lambda = 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

The expression

$\lambda - \frac{\lambda(\lambda - 1)}{2!} + \frac{\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)}{3!}-\ldots = 1 - (1-1)^\lambda = 1$.

arises from a derivation of Euler's totient $\phi(n)$ that uses inclusion/exclusion rather than induction. The expression appears in G.B. Mathews' book Number Theory. It isn't necessary to read his derivation for the totient in which this expression arises, but that is the context, in case anyone is interested.

By successively factoring $\lambda, \lambda-1, \ldots$ I can see how it works intuitively, for example

$$\lambda(1-(\lambda-1)(1+(\lambda-2)(\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{\lambda-3}{4!}+\ldots)))$$

leads to cancellation of $\lambda$.

My main questions are how one sees that this precisely is 1 minus the binomial expansion $(1-1)^\lambda$ and how one deals with whether or not $\lambda$ is even or odd (hence affecting whether the cancellation in my intuitive statement results in a $\lambda$ left over or not).

Comment: The problem is an easy consequence of binomial theorem if $\lambda$ is positive integer. The result is true even if $\lambda$ is a positive real number and then the result follows from general binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have by the binomial formula that
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k} b^{k}$$
so if you put $a=-b=1$ you get
$$(1-1)^\lambda=\sum_{k=0}^\lambda\frac{\lambda!}{k!(\lambda-k)!}(-1)^k=1-\frac{\lambda}{1!}+\frac{\lambda(\lambda-1)}{2!}-\dots\pm \frac{\lambda!}{(\lambda-1)!\cdot 1!}\mp\frac{\lambda!}{\lambda!\cdot 0!}$$
which is exactly what is claimed.